# Basic AutoHotKey Use For Multiple Key Presses

Tags: autohotkey

How can I use AutoHotKey to simulate pressing control quote, then the menu bar button, then the down arrow when I press control p?

As a beginner, I have just been fiddling around with it, but I did not manage to make it work.

```
>^p::
Send ^{'}
Send {AppsKey}
Send {Down}
```

Right now, to me at least, it seems as though the only line of the code that is executing is "Send ^{'}" without anything under it executing.

Comment: Try adding `Sleep , 500` (500ms delay) between your `Send` lines.